# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate not running validations on subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Here's my model:

```
'use strict';
var nested = new Schema({
    name: String
});

var test = new Schema({
    url   : {
        type      : String,
        // First validation
        validate  : [validator.isURL, 'Invalid URL']
    },
    array : [
        {
            type: nested,

            // Second Validation
            validate: [function(value) {console.log("CALLED"); return value.length <=3;}, 'Too long']
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = Parent.discriminator('Test', test);;
```

Here's how I create a new document:

```
Test.findOrCreate({url: url}, function(err, model, created) {
    if (created) {
        model.array = whatever;
    }

    model.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {return res.status(422).json(err);}

        next();
    });
});
```

And here's the update:

```
Test.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set: {array: whatever}}, {new: true, runValidators: true}, function(err, model) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(422).json(err);
    }

    res.status(200).json(model);
});
```

Assume `whatever` contains an array with length 4 on both cases (new and update).

When creating a new model, both validations work as expected and I get an error. However, when using `findByIdAndUpdate`, only the first validation is run and the one on the `array` attribute is ignored (it's not even called). What gives?

Comment: Isn't this explained in the documentation? findByIdAndUpdate ignores validations and hooks? (defaults, setters, validators, and middleware all ignored) Kinda surprised it even ran the first validator.

Comment: @KevinB It does. The `runValidators` options is set to `false` by default, but I've set it to `true` on my code, which probably allows to run the first one, but not the second (the one on the subdocuments). It runs pretty much all validators on my model except the one on the subdocument's array. Is there a better way to do this? I need to update my documents through a PUT (actually a PATCH), and the only other alternative I can see is using `find` and then `save`, which makes the purpose of `findByIdAndUpdate` quite confusing to me.

Answer (score 10):

According to the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html), validators seems to work only for `update()` and `findOneAndUpdate()` if `runValidators` is set to true.

Have you tried:

```
Test.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, {$set: {array: whatever}}, {new: true, runValidators: true}, function(err, model) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(422).json(err);
    }

    res.status(200).json(model);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**Validators do not work on findByIdAndUpdate** (not sure, but didn't work in my case), you can use a middleware to get rid of validators but you need to write some extra code.

Middleware will look like this

```
[SCHEMA].pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next){
    // findOneAndUpdate and findByIdAndUpdate, will fire this hook

    console.log(this.getUpdate()); // it will return the update Object
    console.log(this.getQuery());  // it will return the query object
    // Do all validation here and modify the update object
    // this.getUpdate().url = 'stackoverflow.com';

    // for sub-docs you need to use loop;
    if(this.getUpdate() && Array.isArray(this.getUpdate().array))
        this.getUpdate().array = this.getUpdate().array.map(function(val){
            return (val.length <= 3) ? true : 'To Long';
        }); 

    // after all validation call next
    next();
});
```

Comment: if you are using `$set` then `this.getUpdate()` will give an object like this `{$set: {array: []}}`